# Check is windows drive exists

Tags: c#, windows

I'm going to write C# code that checks Is the C,D,E... (Windows disk drive) exists, or not? And finally find that which drive exists in client windows, to copy there my files.

I want to write the code similar to the following logic:

```
If ( !Exist(Drive "C:\" ) )
{
   If ( !Exist(Drive "D:\" ) )
   {
      If ( !Exist(Drive "E:\" ) )
      {
         ...
         search to fined existence drive
         copy file to a path of that existence drive
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Use [DriveInfo.GetDrives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: +1 @R.S BeCoz Good Questions always appropriated by up voting here.,

Comment: @RJK धन्यवाद . I think my answer was so amateur :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
   //Get Drive names with DriveInfo.GetDrives()
 var drives= DriveInfo.GetDrives();

       foreach (var item in drives)
       {
           //Do Something
       }
```

**Edited**(Check exist)

```
   var drives= DriveInfo.GetDrives();
       if (drives.Where(data => data.Name == "C:\\").Count() == 1 &&
           drives.Where(data => data.Name == "D:\\").Count() == 1 &&
           drives.Where(data => data.Name == "E:\\").Count() == 1)
       {

       }
```

Comment: I see your edit too. thanks, your answer helps me so much! I wish I had enough reputation to vote you up... :(

Comment: chakhlesim (chakker o mokhlesim) :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use Directory.Exists() to check if directory exists.

```
foreach (DriveInfo item in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
        if (Directory.Exists(item.Name))
        {
            // item.name is existed
        }
}
```

You can learn about that from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx).